# compare string with list and print only matched keywords in python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

```
frontvar="risk management system application tracking system digital signature computer systems "

listvar = ['c','computer system','tracking','management',etc]

matchedkeys =[i for i in listvar if i in frontvar]

output :['c',
 'ca',
 'com',
 'computer systems',
 'eme',
 'git',
 'io',
 'man',
 'management',
 'nat',
 'om',
 'ppl',
 'r',
 're',
 'tal',
 'track',
 'tracking']
```

the list(listvar) is very big

i want to print exactly matched words like computer,computer system,risk management system etc.. it should not print junk values like('nat',
 'om',
 'ppl',
 'r',
 're',
 'tal',
 'track')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match just a single word from `frontvar`, just change

`matchedkeys = [i for i in listvar if i in frontvar]`

to

`matchedkeys = [i for i in listvar if i in frontvar.split()]` as @mVChr suggested.

To match multiple words, I'd suggest either using a tuple as mVChr suggested (not sure why that wasn't working for you, you'd have to post an update), or to do as follows:

`matchedkeys = [i for i in listvar if all([j in frontvar.split() for j in i.split()])]`

This will get anything in `listvar` if every word in `listvar` is also a word in `frontvar`. (I use "word" here to describe substrings separated by whitespace.)

I'm not sure if this is actually what you want, your question is slightly unclear to me and I don't have enough reputation to comment. If you're doing something a bit more complicated, a regex might also be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for substring match, not word match.

Just change:

```
matchedkeys = [i for i in listvar if i in frontvar]
```

To:

```
matchedkeys = [i for i in listvar if i in frontvar.split()]
```

Splitting the `frontvar` string into a list will match against the words in `frontvar` instead of the characters in the string.

Comment: if we split only displays 1 word but i want two words  three words etc...

Comment: Then construct a tuple by hand... `('risk management', 'computer systems', ...etc...)`

Comment: for tuple also getting same result